# Is restarting host instance mandatory while changing the stored procedures?

Tags: biztalk

In BizTalk 2010, I am using the SQL Adapter for polling a table to create a message and to initiate the orchestration process.

I have modified the stored procedure without changing the schema. But i have started getting errors after modifying it and SQL polling is not happening. So i have restarted the Host instance and it started working.

So here my question is Is restarting host instance mandatory after changing the stored procedures?

Error is "The adapter "WCF-Custom" raised an error message. Details "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.AdapterException: The ResultSet returned as part of the Typed Stored Procedure or Typed Polling invocation did not match the metadata available. If this Stored Procedure or Polling Statement can return a variable number of result sets, consider using the un-typed Stored Procedure or un-typed Polling operation instead."

Can anyone please suggest what could be the root cause?

Thanks,
Sasikumar.S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will need to restart the Host Instance of the Host configured for your WCF-SQL Handler.

Under the hood, the first time a particular Stored Proc is called, the WCF-SQL adapter first executes it with the SET FMTONLY ON; flag.  This causes Sql Server to return just the datatypes of the expected data, but not execute the sproc itself.  The adapter caches these datatypes for the lifetime of the host process.

If you change the data returned by the stored procedure, the next time it executes, it will be out of sync, and unable to coerce into the expected type.  Hence, the need to restart the Host Instance(s).

TL;DR - If you change a stored procedure, you need to restart the WCF-SQL Host Instance.